# How to use scipy.interpolate.Rbf in N dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to use Rbf for interpolation of a function defined in a 45-dimensional space. How can I insert spacial coordinates into scipy.interpolate.Rbf ?

The syntax is `Rbf(x, y, z, d)`

Is there a way to put `x, y, z` as one list/array because in my case it is `x1, x2, ..., x45`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your points and data are contained in a single Numpy array you can use the unpack syntax `*array` in the function call

```
In [4]: a = np.arange(30)
In [5]: a = a.reshape((6,5))    
In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])

In [7]: f = Rbf(*a)    
In [8]: f((2,3),(7,8),(12,13),(17,18),(22,23))
Out[8]: array([ 27.,  28.])
```

Of course you can also use the same syntax when *using* the function computed by `Rbf`

```
In [9]: x = np.array((4,9,14,19,24))
In [10]: f(*x)
Out[10]: array(29.0)
```